# How do I create a simple graphic design without my jpeg changing colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

When I design a simple postcard in Photoshop and use one of my photos, I'm not sure what color space or how to save the file so that it won't change the color of the image.  When I use CYMK it turns the photos I use neon and RGB looks like someone unsaturated the file.

Comment: Are you printing at home on a home inkjet printer? Or is it for commercial printing, using lithography/screen printing, or something else? Please supply more information if you want a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr Any answer really.

Answer (score 0):

- For an end-user inkjet printer, use RGB colors.
- For a commercial printing press use CMYK colors.

If colors are not accurate when printed, [calibrate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=calibrating) your devices.

Without more information with respect to the actual printing process you are using (equipment), this is the best I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule #1**
Don't use your monitor profile as your colour space. At minimum use your intended output space - sRGB for web, etc. Your monitor profile should appear in the list of potential spaces, but never select it for your Working Space.

[image]

As this seems to be something of a contentious issue [see comments], let me refer to Adobe's own colour workflow documentation - https://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/color_managed_raw_workflow.pdf

Extract -

[image]

Note: most 'consumer' printing facilities prefer sRGB even though the result will be ink-printed, which in 'pro' terms would need CMYK.

<sup>...another 'not really an answer' but based on current question & lack of real detail</sup>

Comment: So according to this rule if you calibrate your monitor to be sRGB . Then you should never use sRGB since its the monitors profile?

Comment: ermm...no. The monitor's profile will be 'DellU2713-sRGB-16May18.icc'... etc The workflow profile would be sRGB IEC61966-2.1. Two entirely different things. The OS automatically applies your monitor profile to what you're seeing, so "doing it twice" is not going to work.

Comment: Yes offcourse but that one is for the system not you. But this is only if your monitor is only profiled not if its hardware calibrated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. It's your monitor profile - whether or not it's calibrated merely affects its accuracy, not its purpose. You absolutely do not want your monitor profile in your Workflow. Example added to answer.

Comment: Calibration is not just more accurate it makes the profile of the device other profile, so after calibration to sRGB the monitors profile is the same sRGB as you would use for documents.

Comment: really, no - the monitor profile is 'how to adjust the colours of this document so they look right on this screen'. It is in no way portable, that's why your Working Space should be your output intent, in this case sRGB.

Comment: Yes but profiling is different form calibration. Profiling is how soes this look wrong. Calibartiuon is make this show exactly this, so once you calibrate you dont get a profile of your monitor it IS sRGB the same sRGB as the one you use

Comment: This is now going round in circles. I quit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77567/discussion-between-joojaa-and-tetsujin).

Comment: Citation added to answer.

Comment: Yes, but its not actually wrong, per see,  to use that profile. Just that it may be counter productive for some workflows. But fine for others justr as long as you embed the profile. Which would be pointless for calibrated displays.